# Use value returned from function to use in an if statement

Tags: javascript

I have a function to check for screen size

```js
function isMob() {
  if ($(window).width() < 1000) {
     return true;
  } else {
     return false;
  }
}

$(window).resize(function() {
  isMob();
});

if (isMob()) {
  console.log('this is a mobile');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Previously I was checking it as a variable `isMob = false;`, but now that I am using the resize function I believe that I need to put it in a function.

I have taken many approaches but not sure how I can replicate the behavior of a simple variable to check if `isMob = true`, and if so trigger an action.

Comment: Well, `if(isMob)` checks if `isMob` is *truthy*, and since it's a function object, it *is* truthy. You'll need to *call* the function to get its result: `if(isMob())`. How that fits in with the `resize` callback I don't know, because I don't know what you want to achieve there.

Comment: Well, now the problem is that your function never returns `true`…

Comment: So, is it working?

Comment: @deceze no, still not, which is what i am surprised at

Comment: *How* isn't it working? What does it do, what do you want it to do?

Comment: @deceze shit! it is working, i prob deserve a lot of down votes, or at least have it closed, sorry, and thanks for ur help!

Answer (score 0):

Try to define a global variable like bellow:

```
var isMobile=isMob();

function isMob() {
    if($(window).width() > 1000) {
        return false;
    }
  return true;
}

$(window).resize(function() {
    isMobile=isMob();
});

if(isMobile){
    console.log('this is a mobile'); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can simply move last `if()` into the `onresize`Handler like so:

```
            function isMob() {
                if ($(window).width() < 1000) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            $(window).resize(function() {
                if (isMob()) {
                    console.log('this is a mobile');
                }
            });
```